# Misssing ServerSocketFactory in tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, ajp, tomcat8.5

As per the below link

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6164, the following features are removed from tomcat 8.5

a) Class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.ServerSocketFactory no longer exists

b) Class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory no longer exists

c) Method JSSEImplementaton.getServerSockerFactory(AbstractEndpoint) no longer exists

d) Method JSSEImplementaton.getSSLUtil(AbstractEndpoint) no longer exists

These make our upgrade from tomcat 8.0 to tomcat 8.5.x difficult.

We have two requirements

1. Tomcat AJP protocol receives encrypted content coming from the HTTP server and gives an encrypted response. This was possible with tomcat 8, by using custom classes implementing tomcat's ServerSocketFactory interface.
2. Store certificates file for tomcat https in a custom keystore (an XML file)

How these can be achieved in tomcat 8.5? Any suggestions appreciated. (We were doing it in Tomcat 8 using custom SocketFcatory implementing tomcat's interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the connector refactoring the `JIoEndpoint` that allowed to specify arbitrary `ServerSocketFactory` is no longer available.

However the AJP connector is almost ready to accept SSL connections if you allow some changes to Tomcat's codebase: the [`AbstractAjpProtocol`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/5ac227ded1eb966daddcaf4b5b22ae0b8a17b697/java/org/apache/coyote/ajp/AbstractAjpProtocol.java#L226) class just lacks an implementation of the `addSslHostConfig` and `findSslHostConfigs` or better it has implementations that don't store or return anything with a very explicit comment:

> SSL is not supported in AJP

If you change them as in [`AbstractHttp11Protocol`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/5ac227ded1eb966daddcaf4b5b22ae0b8a17b697/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11Protocol.java#L651), you'll be able to configure an AJP connector the same way you configure a HTTP/1.1 connector:

```xml
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3">
    <SSLHostConfig ...>
        <Certificate ... />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Regarding the certificate storage you can implement your own [`KeyStoreSpi`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStoreSpi.html) and security provider and use:

```xml
<Certificate certificateKeystoreProvider="your_provider"
             certificateKeystoreType="your_type"
             ... />
```

Comment: Thank you. I had contacted tomcat users group also. The answer I got  was also in similar directions

Comment: The answer from the tomcat-users group was not as detailed as yours. So your answer helped me. However, my final requirement is to read the certificate from a custom key store for AJP SSL also. Our Keystore already implements 
java.security.KeyStoreSpi. However I am not quite clear  which classes in tomcat I should focus on making use of it. Do you have any guidelines?

Comment: You must create, test and register a custom security `Provider` (cf. [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/howtoimplaprovider.htm)) which will provide only your custom keystore type. Once that is done you just need to provide `certificateKeystoreType` in the `<Certificate>` element and Tomcat should use it.